# "Fail to register a this time" error in my android app

Tags: android, firebase, runtime-error

I am facing the Error **"Fail to register at this time"** while registering a user in my android app. kindly help to resolve it.

Comment: Hi Can you please share your line of code for more understanding in api calling flow or other parameter you using or anything you missing.

Comment: What is the code that produces that error?

Comment: it was working fine. I received an email from firebase continuously that update your security rules otherwise will not be able to access firebase. I update rules as true to false. after that getting this error even now I have reverted the rules but still same issue.